# The difference between two sets of tuples

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that takes a tuple (representing an integer coordinate in the plane) and returns all adjacent coordinates **not including the original coordinate**.

```
def get_adj_coord(coord):
    '''
    coord: tuple of int

    should return set of tuples representing coordinates adjacent
    to the original coord (not including the original)
    '''

    x,y = coord

    range1 = range(x-1, x+2)
    range2 = range(y-1, y+2)

    coords = {(x,y) for x in range1 for y in range2} - set(coord)

    return coords
```

The issue is that the return value of this function always includes the original coordinate:

```
In [9]: get_adj_coord((0,0))
Out[9]: {(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)}
```

I'm probably missing something fundamental to sets and/or tuples, but the following function is definitely not returning what I expect. I also tried also using:

```
coords = {(x,y) for x in range1 for y in range2}.remove(coord)
```

But then function returns nothing. Can anyone point out what I'm very clearly missing here?

Comment: `set(coord)` --> `set((coord,))`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks. much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're not subtracting the right set object. Your current approach uses `set((0,0)) -> {0}` which casts the tuple into a set.
However, what you want is a tuple in a set:

```
coords = {(x,y) for x in range1 for y in range2} - {coord}
```

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot. Thanks for pointing that out. Must be time to get out and take a break...